# define UIButton programmatically swift

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I'm trying to add a button programmatically as follows.

```
    lazy var myButton: UIButton = {
       let button = UIButton(type: .System)
       button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
       button.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
       button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height / 2)
       button.addTarget(self, action: "buttonAction", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
       return button
    }()
```

My intention was to create a button with view's width and height, half of view's height. And I also have LeftAnchor, RightAnchor, WidthAnchor, TopAnchor constraints to this button.

I have the following piece of code in my `viewDidLoad()`

```
view.addSubview(myButton)
```

when I try to run this code, I'm not able to see exactly what i want to have on my simulator. 
I would like to see button width = view' width and height of button = view height /2

instead I see small button on the left top of the simulator. How do i resolve this issue?

Thanks !

Comment: The behavior you describe suggests you *have not* defined the constraints, which, along with not posting them, appears to say the issue is there. Could you please post the code defining the constraints?

Comment: `myButton.rightAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.rightAnchor).active = true        myButton.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.widthAnchor).active = true       myButton.leftAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.leftAnchor).active = true       myButton.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.topAnchor).active = true`     This is my constraint code that i have written

Comment: That looks like Swift 2 code, as in Swift 3 it's isActive. Correct? Also, have you tried leading/trailing instead of left/right?

Comment: Additionally, but probably not helpful. I do things differently. I define my controls as simple "let" or "var" and further define them in *viewDidLoad* or wherever I should. (Otherwise, I subclass with a convenience init instead of making the control a property - I think that's the correct term for how you are doing it. One thing that *may* matter though is the "lazy" declaration. Have you tried (1) removing it, or (2) flat out defining things instead of making it a property?

Answer (score 1):

A better bet would be to use AutoLayoutConstraints.

```
var myButtonHeight: NSLayoutConstraint

view.addSubview(myButton)
myButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor).isActive = true
myButtonHeight = myButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.5)
myButtonHeight.isActive = true
```

It's not clear from your comment if changing of the button height is `onTouchDown`, of if its a toggle as a result of `onTouchUpInside`, but either way

```
myButtonHeight.constant = (buttonShouldBeTall) ? 20 : 0
view.setNeedsLayout()
```

Please keep in mind you'll need to position the leading/trailing/centerX anchor and leading/trailing/centerY anchor as well, depending on where you need it to be

Comment: i used this earlier. but my requirement is to change the height of the button when it is clicked. If i use autolayout, Xcode is not allowing me to do change the height of button because of the constraints. Any other idea?